# How can I check with SQL if variable is exist in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating function (PHP) which has to run every few hours and update some DB table.
1. If row isn't exist - `INSERT` new row
2. If row exist - `UPDATE` the current row

I want to write it the easiest and simplest way cause I'll do it for several tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the `insert . . . on duplicate key update` statement:

```
insert into dbtable(cols, . . . )
    select <values here >
    on duplicate key update col2 = values(col2), col3 = values(col3);
```

It is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

EDIT:

Assuming you have some unique key on animals, your query would look something like:

```
insert into animals(animal_id, animal_name)
    select @animal_id, @animal_name
    on duplicate key update animal_name = values(animal_name);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, let's assume that the table name is "animals" and I want to update the col "animal_name" if it has changed or insert new row if it doesn't exist.